# Recorrer una estructura de datos buscando que sean iguales (referencia a memoria)?

Tags: java, punteros, ingenieria-del-software

Tengo una clase que es Lugar que tiene una serie de datos, estos los almaceno en un array dado que a la hora de construir los objetos puede haber varios con el mismo, entonces la idea es recorrer el array pero comparando a nivel de referencia.

¿Que tan buena practica es esto en java?, en la universidad sí que lo usamos pero he visto por ahí comentarios negativos.

Comment: A los que votan para cerrar esta pregunta: No creo que esta pregunta deba ser cerrada ya que, aunque sí que admite cierto grado de subjetividad, este es mínimo. Por otro lado, la pregunta está bastante enfocada. Considero que a más de uno le puede interesar saber cuáles serían los problemas a los que se puede enfrentar si decide llevar a cabo este tipo de comparaciones.

Comment: Yo creo incluso que no hay ningún grado de subjetividad. Está preguntando si es una buena práctica o no, y creo que la respuesta es la que le di y ésta es clara y definida. Si alguno no piensa así debería iluminarnos y que aprendamos que para eso esta [es.so]

Comment: Opino igual en java el objeto lo creas una vez y usaras referencias, pero al hablar con gente que viene con bastante desarrollo en C y leer en esos sitios cosas sobre punteros y posibles errores solo hizo que tuviera esa duda coincido en que la respuesta fue la correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es saber si dos variables distintas apuntan al mismo objeto es una buena práctica y es correcto. Si lo que deseas saber es si dos variables distintas apuntan a objetos que contienen los mismo datos pero no son el mismo (clones) entonces no te vale eso si no implementar el método `equals`.

Comment: Gracias eso tenia yo entendido, pero debido a unos debates que leí ya me quede con la duda, gracias.